# scraping the linked page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

here , i've got data in terms of jobs but here i want to get description from href link, i've done some code where i put the comment but it is returning script in output where i want only description of the job which is on next page.

```
url = f"https://weworkremotely.com/remote-jobs/search?term={keyword}"
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
section = soup.find_all("section", {"class": "jobs"})
for item in section:
    a = item.select("li > a")
    for item2 in a:
        if str(item2.parent['class']) != "['view-all']":
            link = f"https://weworkremotely.com{item2.get('href')}"
            htmll = requests.get(link, headers=headers).text  #this is how i'm trying to get description from new page
            soupp = BeautifulSoup(htmll, 'lxml')
            print(soupp.prettify)
            apply_list.append(link)
        else:
            continue

return company_list, title_list, apply_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you with get_text() instead?
Or if site you wish to scrape is heavily featured by Javascript then would suggest switching to Selenium

```
html = requests.get(link, headers=headers).get_text()
```